# nodejs deployment on heroku failed

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to develop an application using nodejs. running on localhost environment but developing on heroku the error message appears "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"

heroku logs --tail

```
2019-11-21T14:35:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-11-21T14:35:32.004793+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-21T14:35:32.004818+00:00 app[web.1]: > demo@1.0.0 start /app
2019-11-21T14:35:32.004820+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/index.js
2019-11-21T14:35:32.004822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-21T14:35:32.611732+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Started
2019-11-21T14:35:32.949266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-11-21T14:36:02.357158+00:00 app[web.1]: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
2019-11-21T14:36:02.369616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-21T14:36:02.370031+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-11-21T14:36:02.371505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! demo@1.0.0 start: `node src/index.js`
2019-11-21T14:36:02.371733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-21T14:36:02.371962+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-11-21T14:36:02.372192+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the demo@1.0.0 start script.
2019-11-21T14:36:02.372407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-21T14:36:02.381032+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-21T14:36:02.381214+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-21T14:36:02.381392+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-21T14_36_02_373Z-debug.log
2019-11-21T14:36:02.441737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-11-21T14:36:02.446392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-21T14:36:02.427080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1       
2019-11-21T14:36:04.386161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm 
start`
2019-11-21T14:36:06.423071+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-21T14:36:06.423091+00:00 app[web.1]: > demo@1.0.0 start /app
2019-11-21T14:36:06.423093+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/index.js
2019-11-21T14:36:06.423094+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-21T14:36:07.101163+00:00 app[web.1]: Server Started
2019-11-21T14:36:07.532553+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up  
2019-11-21T14:36:36.819665+00:00 app[web.1]: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
2019-11-21T14:36:36.829253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-21T14:36:36.829569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-11-21T14:36:36.831231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! demo@1.0.0 start: `node src/index.js`
2019-11-21T14:36:36.831566+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-11-21T14:36:36.831890+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-11-21T14:36:36.832164+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the demo@1.0.0 start script.
2019-11-21T14:36:36.832423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-11-21T14:36:36.843750+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-11-21T14:36:36.843979+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-11-21T14:36:36.844171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-11-211T14_36_36_833Z-debug.log
2019-11-21T14:36:36.919267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed    
2019-11-21T14:36:36.898959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

The application runs on the localhost environment without errors

Comment: Share the code snippet that caused this error and also give context to that code. That will help the developers really understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error in log looks like you are trying to connect to mongodb that runs locally on your pc. If that is the case, then heroku is unable to connect to your local mongodb. You can try to create a mongodb instance, that would be available to accept connections from heroku, using free cloud services like mlab.

**Update:** 
The problem was in start script that was using nodemon

Comment: i'm using code connect to mlab
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
        return 'mongodb://<user>:<passowd>@ds219055.mlab.com:19055/library';

    return 'mongodb://localhost:27017/manageLibrary';

Comment: Did you commit and push to heroku after making these changes?

Comment: yes, i create new one app different, and push to heroku, but errors too

Comment: this is heroku logs : https://github.com/phanthinhphu/errorNodejs/blob/master/New%20Text%20Document.txt

Comment: try to remove your start script from package.json and redeploy the app to heroku, then give feedback